# Angular observables get canceled

Tags: angular, request, promise, observable

I'm building an Angular 2 web app that makes requests to a backend that does some computational work. There are models, each of which has an associated metric, that is applied to a set of scenarios.

In the service that handles communication with the backend, I have two methods: `simulateScenario` and `handleData`

```
simulateScenario(model: Model, scenarioID: string): Observable<any> {
    const modelID = model.id;
    let scenario = this.scenariosService.getScenario(modelID, scenarioID);
    let metric = this.metricsService.getSelectedMetric(modelID);

    let params: URLSearchParams = metric.getMetricParams();
    // ...set params...

    return this.http.get(this.apiEndpoint + metric.endpoint, {search: params})
    .map(res => this.handleData(res, scenario, metric))
    .catch((error: any) => {
        console.log(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
    });
}

private handleData(res: Response, scenario: Scenario, metric: Metric): void {        
    const body = res.json();
    scenario.feasibility = metric.feasibility(body);
    let data = metric.getPlotData(body);

    scenario.setData(data);
}
```

When I update a single scenario in the component that has them, everything works as expected:

```
addRow(): void {
  let newScenario = ...
  this.computeService.simulateScenario(this.model, newScenario.id);
    .subscribe();
}
```

But, when a global setting changes, some of the observables don't complete or have canceled requests. This is how I trigger a reevaluation of all current scenarios:

```
 onGlobalsChanged(event: any): boolean {
   for (let iter = 0; iter < this.scenarios.length; iter++) {
     this.computeService.simulateScenario(this.model, this.scenarios[iter].id);
      .subscribe();
   }
 }
```

The scenarios that don't get handled and the requests that get canceled seem to be random and dependent on which results happen to finish on the backend first.

After a couple of days trying to figure out what was going on, I found a reference to Promises being uncancellable. On a hunch, I converted the Observables to Promises in the code above, and everything seems to work. As I understand it, this is not a longterm best practice.

So, my questions boil down to

- Why do the observables above get cancelled?
- Is there a way to change my pattern of use that would avoid the cancellation? (for instance setting an 'uncancellable' option)
- Is using 'toPromise' really a bad practice going forward, if not, what are the criteria to use it?

Comment: Indeed, why do they get cancelled? [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help to answer this question. It is not clear what you mean by 'cancelled' and how you expect them to behave. If there is an error, it should be caught.

Comment: There's not an error that occurs. As best I can tell, the browser determines (incorrectly) that some of the observables can be cancelled because they're no longer relevant. At that point, the browser aborts the HTTP request if the connection is still alive, furthermore it doesn't call the `map` block on some of the requests already returned.

Comment: Then MCVE is needed to replicate the problem. A working fiddle or plunk is welcome. It is not uncommon that the problem itself is solved during its reproduction. It is not obvious that you handle errors properly in the code above. `.subscribe()` is most important part in the context of the problem, and it is missing.